# Graphical editor for GSettings/dconf?

Tags: dconf, gsettings

Is there an equivalent to gconf-editor for GSettings/dconf?

I know that I can use `gsettings set ...` on the command line, but that's a bit inconvenient (especially with list types).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There's `dconf-editor`, which is the equivalent to `gconf-editor`. To install it, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

For old Ubuntu versions (before 14.04), `dconf-editor` is provided by the `dconf-tools` package. You can install it by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Comment: Yes, but note http://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database

Comment: Currently, provided by `dconf-editor` package. (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @TomBerghuis right above yours.

Comment: dconf-editor doesn't actually look into gsettings database.